# How to add 'Attachment Display Settings' in custom Media Library?

Tags: media-library

By default, when clicking on insert media and selecting an image, we get 'Attachment Display Settings'.

I am creating a custom Media Library for a Custom Post using the following code:

```
customImageManagementTool = wp.media.frames.customImageManagementTool = wp.media({
    className: 'media-frame tgm-media-frame',
    multiple: true,
    title: "Select Images",
    library: {
        type: 'image'
    },
    button: {
        text: "Insert selection"
    }
});
```

`customImageManagementTool.open()` invokes the Media Library, but does not include 'Attachment Display Settings' in the popup.

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
frame: 'post',
```

to wp.media attributes. There are two types of pre-built frames in WordPress 3.5 – post and select. Select is the default frame type and it is the interface that is created in the custom-header.js file.

The post frame is what appears when we click on the Add Media button while editing posts or pages.

Information from http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/how-to-add-the-wordpress-3-5-media-manager-interface-part-2